# FBML elements rendering delay

Tags: facebook, fbml

I am using FBML for rendering certain elements on the page such as the name of the user, profil pic, etc. However when there are many FBML elements on page, there is a slight delay which occurs before they are rendered - that's fine since AJAX calls are made to the server to fetch the data by the JS FB library. However, I want to hide the container DIV holding these element till the elements have finished loading, so is there any way to specify a JS callback function which gets fired when the FBML data has finished loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe)

```
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function(response) {
  //xfbml.render is fired when a call to FB.XFBML.parse() completes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option for this. First, make sure you have the `xfbml=0` parameter set on all embeds. Next, you can use this small bit of jQuery:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
  FB.XFBML.parse(null,function(){
      // all FB embeds are rendered as of this point
  });
};
```